# WCF Windows form client object reference error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've done a wcflibrary and hosted this in a windows service. For the client I did a windows form. But now when I try to run the windows form it says:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here's the code for my client:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  //  ICalculator calcService = null;
  //  IMyWorld myworldService = null;

   ServiceReference1.ICalculator channel = null;
   ServiceReference2.IMyWorld channeln = null;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DuplexChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.ICalculator> factory = null;
        DuplexChannelFactory<ServiceReference2.IMyWorld> factoryn = null;
        var callbackClient = new CallBackClient();
        var callbackClientn = new CallBackClientn();
        var context = new InstanceContext(callbackClient);
        var contextn = new InstanceContext(callbackClientn);
        factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.ICalculator>(context, "ServiceTCPEndPoint");               
        factoryn = new DuplexChannelFactory<ServiceReference2.IMyWorld>(contextn, "ServiceTCPEndPoint1");
         channel = factory.CreateChannel();
         channeln = factoryn.CreateChannel();
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        channel.AddTo(1.1);      **Here is where I'm getting the error**
        channeln.Hello();

        channel.SubtractFrom(2.0);
        channel.MultiplyBy(6.0);
        channel.DivideBy(2.0);
        channel.Clear();
    }
```

And in the locals the variable 'channel' stays as null. Why doesn't it get assigned in the 'Form1_Load' event.

Any clues.

Comment: did you put a breakpoint in the form_load to see what happens ?

Comment: yes it goes back to the form after factory, so I can't view the variables after factory

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see where the NRE happens?  If `channel` is null after the `Form1_Load` event then something didn't happen as you expected in the method.